# Getting Azure oauth2 token from Javascript not working always

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get aouth2 access token using java script by calling a mvc action method to access the web api methods.

Here I am checking every 30 seconds whether the token is expired or not if it expires if trying to get the new token.The problem here is this is working if I remove below line of code

```
 if (Inittoken != null && Inittoken.accessToken.expires_on < currentdatetime)
```

If I put the condition it is not able to get the token .I am getting the CORS error as Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with 302 error. What I can not understand is why it is working if I try to get the token continuously every 30 seconds(even if it not expires) and why it is not working when I try to get the token only it expires. I know the token will be expired after an hour

```
 setInterval(
         function () {
             var currentdatetime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;         
             if (Inittoken != null && Inittoken.accessToken.expires_on < currentdatetime) {

                 $.ajax({
                url: '/Common/GetAccessTokenJS',
                success: function (data) {
                    resonsedata = data;
                    settings.accessToken = JSON.parse(resonsedata);
                },
                error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                    console.log("failed to get access token");
                    console.log(errorObj);
                }
            });          
            }

         }, 30000);
```

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname/oauth2/token

Comment: Do you have any page caching going on with your MVC page?

Comment: No,I am not using any caching

Comment: I think your back-end is trying to redirect your AJAX request to login at AAD, which won't work. Normally you shouldn't use this kind of interactive authentication on back-end APIs. It should instead implement JSON Web token authentication, and then the front-end can acquire tokens and authenticate the user using the implicit grant flow (with adal.js or MSAL.js).

Comment: @juunas -Thanks for your inputs. But why it is not failing always to get token .

Comment: It could be the session is still active. It probably uses cookies to keep it active.

Comment: @Juunas  -I did not understand session is still active.Can you explain please . We are not using the logged in user credentials to get the token to access the web api methods.We created a separate user  to get the token .We are using that token to call api methods. In /Common/GetAccessTokenJS I am using the separate user(grant-type :password) credentials to get the token. Is there anyway we can check the token expired or not in c# and get a new token (Not using AJAX) and pass that token to front end